# Understanding Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to migrate code from a method I found in Apple's online example code to swift, I have *some* understanding of Objective-C but am missing a few key holes. I understand most of the following code, I'd really appreciate help with the following:

1) Why are there two return statements in the first method? How does it work with both statements?

2) I don't entirely understand the declaration of the second method:

- "buf" is a reference, would that be done with "&" in swift?
- What does "at:(int*)iterator" mean, how would it work in swift?
- What does [buf bytes] in the first line of the second method mean?

The methods:

```
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyMod
{
    NSData* pk = [self getPublicKeyBits:@"RSA Public Key"];
    if (pk == NULL) return NULL;

    int iterator = 0;

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream - mod + exp
    [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator]; // Total size

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream mod
    int mod_size = [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator];

    return [pk subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(iterator, mod_size)];
    return pk;
    NSLog(@"public size: %d",pk.length);
}

- (int)derEncodingGetSizeFrom:(NSData*)buf at:(int*)iterator
{
    const uint8_t* data = [buf bytes];
    int itr = *iterator;
    int num_bytes = 1;
    int ret = 0;

    if (data[itr] > 0x80) {
        num_bytes = data[itr] - 0x80;
        itr++;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < num_bytes; i++) 
        ret = (ret * 0x100) + data[itr + i];

    *iterator = itr + num_bytes;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The double return is an error and would not compile, I suspect.  (In fact, it wouldn't compile anyway because of the NSLog following the `return`.)   `buf` is a simple pointer to an NSData object. `at:(int*)iterator` declares an additional parameter for the method.  To find out what `[buf bytes]` means, refer to the documentation for NSData.

Comment: (You need to know Objective-C *much* better before you can expect to translate it to another language.)

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn’t work with both statements. The code after the first `return` statement would never execute. This method executes serially.

2) Below are answers to your bulleted questions.

- `buf`, in Swift,  would not need to be passed in wtih an `&` unless the you used the `inout` parameter in the method signature for the first argument.  There is no need to do this, as `buf` object is not altered in the method.
- The `at:(int*)iterator` is an input parameter that defines a pointer to an Integer. Because it is a pointer, when it is altered by this method, it is also altered in the caller's scope. It could be ported to Swift using the `inout` keyword in the method signature since it is altered and the calling method expects it to be altered when the method completes execution.  Alternatively you could change the method signature in Swift to return both the new iterator Integer as well as the value it is already returning (`ret`), since Swift allows for multiple return values.
- `[buf bytes]` returns the data encapsulated in the `NSData` instance; the *raw* bytes.  If you wanted to do some bit twiddling, you'd get to the data using the `bytes` method.